# Is it possible to give a type/class to JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I wonder if it's possible to give a a type/class to JavaScript functions.

Of course, the Object class/type of function is 'Function/function'.

http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof

However, in my project, somehow I want to define class for function to group them.

It's similar concept HTML/CSS DOM element class.

I have a function which args is a function, and I want to distinguish which `type` or `class` of function is passed to the function.

It does not work with any object method, just a function, but it can be distinguished like `obj.hasOwnProperty('someClass')` .

I just wonder if there's smart way, if you think impossible, please insist so.

Thanks.

PS. I do not why someone vote -1 and to close this question.

This is the matter of `reflection` of Javascript. It's ok if find some reflection factor of JS is limited. and I think it's not wise to avoid to make it clear that something is impossible in a certain language.

Comment: The type of a Function is "function" and all functions have that same type.  There are not multiple types of functions, So it is not clear what exactly you're trying to do.  Please show an example of two different functions that you want to distinguish?  FYI, functions are objects so they can have your own custom properties so you could make your own custom property that defined what type of your function it was, but it's still unclear what problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks I know that, and actually I illustrate the fact in my question. What I'm trying to do is to `add` some extra class factor to the functions. This is for general approach, not for specific two different functions that I want to distinguish.

Comment: >FYI, functions are objects so they can have your own custom properties so you could make your own custom property. < Great. That is the answer. You successfully understand my question and give a specific answer. If you post it, I will acceept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is an object.  You can add your own custom properties to any function.  So, if you want to set your own type on several different functions so you can test for that, you can just add the same custom property (with different values assigned to it) to each of those functions.

```
function myFunc1() {}
myFunc1.myType = "whatever1";

function myFunc2() {}
myFunc2.myType = "whatever2";

function myFunc3() {}
myFunc3.myType = "whatever3";

function callMe(cb) {
    if (cb.myType === "whatever1") {
        // code here
    } else if (...) {
        // code here
    }
}

callMe(myFunc1);
```

---

Note, this is a bit unusual and if you explained the actual problem you were trying to solve, there is probably a more common design pattern that might help you.

Comment: Thanks. Great. Accepted. and no, this is the sufficient design pattern I exactly need.

Comment: good solution. for consistence (every Function has a defined type) Function could be prototyped before like Function.prototype.myType = 'default';

Comment: Prototyping is a good idea, too. I would do `Function.prototype.class = null;`

Comment: @KenOKABE - I'm not sure adding it to the prototype is necessary.  You can easily test to see if it's been set or not, by just checking if it's not `undefined` which likely works just as well as if you've previously initialized it to `null` via the prototype and now given every single function a property it didn't used to have.  I personally would limit the effect of your change to only the places you need it rather than change every single function.  As I said earlier, if we knew what problem you were really trying to solve, we could also probably recommend a more common design pattern.

Comment: Right, after the post, I noticed 'null' prototyping is meaning less.

Comment: Well, all I can say is to implement `class` for functions like HTML/CSS DOM. That is the exact problem I had. I have a function to receive arg (=function) and potentially, those functions have different contexts, where I need to label as `class`. Do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 0):

@jfriend00 has suggested the answer.

> FYI, functions are objects so they can have your own custom properties so you could make your own custom property.

He's right, so to add a class/property to any functions, simply do

```
var myFunction = function(foo){...};
myFunction['someClass'] = true;

//To distinguish

if (someFunction.hasOwnProperty('someClass'))
      {
        console.log('someFunction is someClass'); 
      }
```